# Position:fixed image overlapping divs

Tags: html, css, z-index

Okay, I'm trying to get an image with position fixed to hide behind specific DIVs.  To my understanding, this should be possible using `z-index`.  However, I've tried everything and cannot get this to work properly.

URL: http://www.aadesigns.net/who-we-are/testimonials/

The image I'm having a problem with is the happy woman celebrating.  Everything works GREAT until it gets to the bottom of the page and you'll see her overlap DIVs.

I've been in firebug for about 1.5 hours trying to figure out how to do this by manipulating z-index...

Any help would be greatly appreciated here.

EDIT* More specifically, I need the image to vanish behind the footer and the footer_bottom DIVs

Comment: Apply `z-index: 9999` to `.testimonials img` and it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `z-index:100` to img inline style. Better convert this inline style to class like below

```
.testimonials img{
    position:fixed;
    left:50%;
     margin-left:-600px;
    bottom:0; 
    z-index:100
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry everyone, I should have been more specific, I need the image to go behind `<div id="footer_bottom">`

Comment: @user1873463 why there are so many styles declared for #footer_bottom??

Comment: Okay, I found the solution, this helped a great deal.  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

apply `z-index: 100;` on `img`

```
<img src="http://www.aadesigns.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/happycustomer1.png" alt="" title="happycustomer" style="position:fixed;left:50%;margin-left:-600px;bottom:0;z-index: 100;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your `#footer z-index:-1;`
**Add this css**

```
#footer{
z-index:-1;
}
```

### -------

**or second option**

```
.testimonials img{
z-index:1;
}
```